# Python: Using DictReader, sort in specific columnn

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I'm trying to sort a specific column or key from my csv file.

Text file looks like this:

```
NameID, StudentName, University, Phone, State
SROGE, Steve Rogers,  UofI, 324324423, New York
JSNOW, Jon Snow, UofWinterfell, 324234423, Westeros
DTARG, Daenerys Targaryen, Dragonstone, 345345, NULL
```

Right now I have a function where it reads the csv file using DictReader and it will print. The other function asks for user input and it should display a sorted column:

```
def load_data(file_name):
university_data=[]
with open("file.csv", mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for col in csv_reader:
      university_data.append(dict(col))
      print(university_data)
return university_data


def main():
    filename='file.csv'
    university_data = load_data(filename)
    print('[1] University\n[2] Student Name\n[3] Exit\n[4] Search')
    while True:

        choice=input('Enter choice 1/2/3? ')
        if choice=='1':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university[2])
        elif choice=='2':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university[1])
        elif choice =='3':
            print('Thank You')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid selection')
main()
```

What I need help on is to make a function(s) where a user selects StudentName(2) (so like Steve Rogers, Jon Snow, Daenerys Targaryen) and it will display a sorted list of a dictionary.

The output should be:

```
{'NameID': 'DTARG', ' StudentName': ' Daenerys Targaryen',' University': ' Dragonstone', ' Phone': ' 345345', ' State': ' NULL'}
{'NameID': 'JSNOW', ' StudentName': ' Jon Snow', ' University': ' UofWinterfell', ' Phone': ' 324234423', ' State': 'Westeros'}
{'NameID': 'SROGE', ' StudentName': ' Steve Rogers', ' University': '  UofI', ' Phone': ' 324324423', ' State': ' NewYork'}
```

Now how do I make a function that displays in a sorted manner based on my program?

Comment: Is it a typo, or did you forget to store the content of the file in `university_data` before returning it? IMHO `university_data.append(col)` is missing in the loop...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have university_data as a return on load_data. I updated university_data.append(col) onto my code, but i'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have some minor problems.

First, the csv file seems to contain spaces after the separator. This requires the option `skipinitialspace=True` when parsing.

Next, `university_data` is a list of dictionaries (if fact `collections.OrderedDict`) and the keys are NameID, StudentName, University, Phone and State.

So you need:

```
def load_data(file_name):
    ...
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
...
def main():
    ...
        if choice=='1':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university['University'])
        ...
```

Same for the other elements...

Comment: I get a KeyError  whenever it does that " print(university['University'])
KeyError: 'University'"

Comment: @smokingpenguin: did you add the `skipinitialspace`? And if you did, please show the first lines of the csv file as plain text.